# Accessing variables from different frames tkinter using 'shared_data' method

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, file-not-found, valueerror

So this is a continuation of the question that I asked here: [How to access user selected file across frames, tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49537957/how-to-access-user-selected-file-across-frames-tkinter?noredirect=1#comment86085577_49537957)

Where I was directed towards the this solution: [How to access variables from different classes in tkinter python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646605/how-to-access-variables-from-different-classes-in-tkinter-python-3)

This is how my code looks currently, there are two functions on page two in my attempts to get the chosen file onto the second page.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import filedialog

    class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "GUI")

        self.shared_data = {
                "filename": tk.StringVar(),
            }

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (Page1, Page2):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(Page1)



    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()



class Page1(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        ftypes = [
                ('CSV files','*.csv')
        ]


        def browsefunc2():
            filename = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=ftypes)

            pathlabel.config(text=filename)

            print(filename)


        browsebutton = tk.Button(self, text="Browse", command=browsefunc2, height=1, width=10)
        browsebutton.pack()

        pathlabel = tk.Label(self)
        pathlabel.pack()

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Page 2",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page2))
        button.pack()



class Page2(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)



        #method one
        def print_df():
            #print(self.controller.shared_data["filename"].get())
            df = pd.read_csv(self.controller.shared_data["filename"].get())
            print(df)

        #method two
        filename__ = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["filename"]) 

        def print_df2():
            #print(filename__)
            df = pd.read_csv(filename__)
            print(df)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Print DF 1", command=print_df)
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Print DF 2", command=print_df2)
        button2.pack()

        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Page 1",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page1))
        button3.pack()

app = GUI()
app.mainloop()
```

However when trying to use the 'tk.Entry' method to get the variable "filename" in Page2, I am faced with the error ".!frame.!page2.!entry" for 'print' and "ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: " for 'read_csv()'.

Alternatively, when trying to use the '.get()' method, I am faced with the error "FileNotFoundError: File b'' does not exist" for both instances

I appreciate that these are several errors for a single question but all I need is one method to work. I have no idea why the solution mentioned above hasn't worked with my code considering it's an almost identical problem.

Any tips would be useful.

Comment: At no point do you actually give a value to the shared `filename` var; `browsefunc2()` just sets a local variable of the same name.

Comment: Ok, so how would I assign it to the shared filename?

Comment: Call `.set(xxx)` on it, just like you call `.get()` to retrieve the value.

Comment: I'm probably being dumb, but I'm putting the line: `self.controller.shared_data["filename"].set(filename)` within the function in order to `set` it, however I'm just getting the same problem as before