# rebuild widget when switching frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, treeview

My tk has 2 frames, each has a treeview, build from a custom treeview object. when a row in 1st frame treeview is selected, it is saved to a variable. when user switches  to 2nd frame by clicking on a button, the value saved from 1st frame will be used as a condition and filter out the treeview in 2nd frame.

I built tried to build my tkinter based the class structure here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7557028/6620144

I added a custom treeview object that is called by both frames.

```
main_tree_selected=None

class program(tk.Tk):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
   ...
      for F in (mainpage, editpage):
         frame = F(container, self)
         .....


class mastertreeview(object):
   def __init__(self, connection, sel_statement, cond_clause=None, cond_value = None)):
   ....
   def populate_tree(self)
   ....


class mainpage(tk.Frame):
   def __init__(self, parent, controller):
   main_tree = mastertreeview(connection, sql_statement, where_clause)
   switch_button = tk.Button(command=lambda: self.controller.show_frame(editpage)
   ....


class editpage(tk.Frame):
   def __init__(self, parent, controller):
   edit_tree = mastertreeview(connection, sql_statement, where_clause, cond_value)
   ....
```

I understand that both frames are setup and build at the same time, including the child widget. **I was wondering whether there is a way I can call the `edit_tree` treeview, and repopulate the tree when `switch_button` is clicked.**

Comment: Based on what you want, I see no advantage to using the code that you got from that other answer. That is not good code to use if you don't understand how it works.

Comment: @bryan-oakley I found one of your older post that discuss how to access variable from a different class - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33650527/6620144) I was wondering whether that would be applicable to my situation?

Comment: If it involves this architecture, I would say no. That architecture was designed for distinct pages that are independent. While you can make it work, it's too complex for such a simple problem.