# python StartPage instance has no attribute 's'

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am getting:

> print (p.s) AttributeError: StartPage instance has no attribute 's'

here is my code:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.s = []
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='we')
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, images_result):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
        self.show_frame("StartPage")
    def get_SP(self):
        return self.frames["StartPage"]
    def images(self, page_name):
        self.s = [1, 2]
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()
    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='snew')
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.image_btn = tk.Button(self, text="Images", command=lambda: controller.images("images_result"))
        self.image_btn.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='snew')



class images_result(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        p = self.controller.get_SP()
        print (p.s)



app = SampleApp()
app.mainloop()
```

**Edited:**

I want the function images in SampleApp to update the attribute s of the SampleApp then I want to be able to access it from the class images_results.

I tried to use

```
print(self.controller.s)
```

but that gives me [] and by that it seems that the modification that has been done by the function images to the s attribute are not visible to the images_result.

Comment: So why do you expect `StartPage` to have an `s` attribute?

Comment: @Aran-Fey I am trying information from one page to another to display it if that is what you meant by your question

Comment: @Aran-Fey somthing similar to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646605/how-to-access-variables-from-different-classes-in-tkinter)

Comment: You realize that `SampleApp` has the `s` attribute, not `StartPage`?

Comment: @Aran-Fey sorry, my bad, I have edited my question please kindly read it again and try to help me

Comment: Are you aware that `images_result` is run when the app starts up, and not after the user interacts with the other pages?

Comment: @BryanOakley thank you, I feel so dummy because I forgot how the classes work when I was focusing on learning tkinter. would you like please write your comment in answer so I approve it so when anyone encounter the same problem he/she finds the answer quickly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only class in your code which as an `s` attribute is `SampleApp`. The instance of this class is passed as the `controller` attribute for each page. Thus, to access the `s` attribute of the `SampleApp` object from within a page will be through the controller:

```
print(self.controller.s)
```

It's important to note that in the code you posted, the `__init__` method of `images_remote` will only run when the app first starts up, so any values set by interacting with the other pages won't be printed by the `__init__` function.

Comment: sorry, my bad, I have edited my question please kindly read it again and try to help me