# User Input Not Displaying on Next Page

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a program that will eventually ask the user to input a filename and graph the data file. However, I'm having difficulty transferring the user input file name into the next page.

I have implemented both answers shown on this page ([How to access variables from different classes in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646605/how-to-access-variables-from-different-classes-in-tkinter)) but unfortunately can't get this to work. I'm thinking that maybe PageOne is being rewritten or that entry_field_variable is getting rewritten or not saved. I'm new to tkinter so I may be making an obvious oversight but any help is appreciated.

```
import tkinter as tk


LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)
NORM_FONT= ("Verdana", 10)
SMALL_FONT= ("Verdana", 8)


class mGui(tk.Tk):  


    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs): 

       tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kargs) 
       container = tk.Frame(self)
       container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
       container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
       container.grid()



       self.shared_data = {"entry_field_variable":tk.StringVar()}

       self.frames = {}  

       for F in (StartPage, PageOne):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")



       self.show_frame(StartPage)   

    def show_frame(self, cont):  
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()   


class StartPage(tk.Frame):  

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):  
        self.controller = controller
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent) 
        label_1 = tk.Label(self, text = "Start Page", font = LARGE_FONT)
        label_1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)


        entry1 = tk.Entry(self, textvariable = self.controller.shared_data["entry_field_variable"])
        entry1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)




        button1 = tk.Button(self,text = "Go", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button1.grid(row = 2, column = 0) 



class PageOne(tk.Frame):  

    def __init__(self, parent, controller): 
        self.controller = controller
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent) 

        label_1 = tk.Label(self, text = "Page One", font = LARGE_FONT)
        label_1.grid(row = 1, column = 4)  

        filename = self.controller.shared_data["entry_field_variable"].get()


        label_2 = tk.Label(self, text = filename, font = LARGE_FONT)
        label_2.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Go Back", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.grid(row = 4, column = 1)              


app = mGui()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea of using a `tk.StringVar` is good, but you are missing a few things:

- you need to collect the value entered in the `entry` field of `StartPage`.
- this value needs to be passed to the controller.
- finally, `PageOne` must have access to it, therefore it is necessary to assign the `tk.StringVar` holding the filename to the label `textvariable`.

Here is how it can be done:

```
import tkinter as tk


LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)
NORM_FONT= ("Verdana", 10)
SMALL_FONT= ("Verdana", 8)


class mGui(tk.Tk):  

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs) 
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid()

        self.shared_data = {"filename": tk.StringVar('')}

        self.frames = {}  
        for PageFrame in (StartPage, PageOne):
            frame = PageFrame(container, self)
            self.frames[PageFrame] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)   

    def show_frame(self, cont):  
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()   


class StartPage(tk.Frame):  

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):  
        self.controller = controller
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent) 
        label_1 = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label_1.grid(row=0, column=0)

        entry1 = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["filename"])
        entry1.grid(row=1, column=0)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go", command=lambda: self.controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button1.grid(row=2, column = 0)


class PageOne(tk.Frame):  

    def __init__(self, parent, controller): 
        self.controller = controller
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent) 

        label_1 = tk.Label(self, text="Page One", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label_1.grid(row = 1, column = 4)  

        filename = self.controller.shared_data["filename"]

        label_2 = tk.Label(self, textvariable=filename, font=LARGE_FONT)
        label_2.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go Back", command=lambda: self.controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.grid(row=4, column=1)              


app = mGui()
app.mainloop()
```