# tkinter can't convert entry string to int

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an entry widget in a class (StartPage) where I have to put numbers, the input is saved in a general class (Variabili) which is accessible from another class (FirstPage). Based on that number I have to istanciate n labels (where n is the number i put in the previous page). To do that I used a for loop:  `for i in range(0, int(number))`. And here's the problem:
I keep getting this error: `TypeError: IntVar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'`

Down here's the code:

```
import tkinter as tk                # python 3
from tkinter import font as tkfont
from typing_extensions import IntVar  # python 3


class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name, *args):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

    def get_page(self, classname):
        '''Returns an instance of a page given it's class name as a string'''
        for page in self.frames.values():
            if str(page.__class__.__name__) == classname:
                return page
        return None



class Variabili: 
    numero_finanziatori = tk.IntVar()
    
class StartPage(tk.Frame, Variabili):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        
        #label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page: insert value")
        #label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        #self.some_input = tk.IntVar()
        #self.some_entry = tk.Entry(self, width=8, textvariable=self.some_input).pack()
        

        self.some_input = tk.StringVar()
        self.some_entry = tk.Entry(self, width=8, textvariable=Variabili.numero_finanziatori)
        self.some_entry.insert(0, "1")
        self.some_entry.pack()
        Variabili.numero_finanziatori = self.some_entry.get()
        
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text='Next Page', command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        button1.pack()

class PageOne(tk.Frame, Variabili):   

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        
        labels_finanziatori = {
        'principale': [],
        'capitale_investito': [], 
        'tasso': [], 
        'tempo': []
        }
        dict_finanziatori = {
        'numero': [],
        'capitale_investito': [], 
        'tasso': [], 
        'tempo': [],
        }
        Finanziatore_Semplice = []

        k = 0

        for i in range(0, int(Variabili.numero_finanziatori)): 
            #MAIN label del finanziatore
            labels_finanziatori['principale'].append(tk.Label(self, text="Dati finanziatore numero "+str(i+1) +":\n"))
            labels_finanziatori['principale'][i].grid(row=i*(k+1), column = 0)
            k = k+1
            button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage")).grid()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

And here's the traceback i get:

```
File "c:/Users/trevi/Documents/WorkInProgress/Python/V0_3/backbone4.py", line 50, in <module>
    class Variabili:
  File "c:/Users/trevi/Documents/WorkInProgress/Python/V0_3/backbone4.py", line 51, in Variabili
    numero_finanziatori = tk.IntVar()
  File "C:\Users\trevi\Anaconda\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 502, in __init__
    Variable.__init__(self, master, value, name)
  File "C:\Users\trevi\Anaconda\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 317, in __init__
    self._root = master._root()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_root'
```

Comment: Your code cannot be run and tested. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and full traceback.

Comment: @8349697 I added the requested details

Comment: The error in the description and the actual error are different.

Answer (score 0):

`IntVar` inherits from the [Variable class](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L316).

```py
from inspect import signature
import tkinter


print("\n----- IntVar Method Resolution Order -----\n")

print(tkinter.IntVar.mro())

print("\n----- __init__ signature -----\n")

print("Variable:", signature(tkinter.Variable.__init__))
print("IntVar:", signature(tkinter.IntVar.__init__))
```

Output:

```
----- IntVar Method Resolution Order -----

[<class 'tkinter.IntVar'>, <class 'tkinter.Variable'>, <class 'object'>]

----- __init__ signature -----

Variable: (self, master=None, value=None, name=None)
IntVar: (self, master=None, value=None, name=None)
```

The point is that calling **IntVar()** requires a **master** (or root window).

From the `Variable class`:

```
if not master:
    master = _get_default_root('create variable')
self._root = master._root()
self._tk = master.tk
```

The reason for this error is that the default root was not found when calling IntVar.
If the `root` is already declared in the script, it is usually not specified as an IntVar parameter.

```py
import tkinter


print("\n----- root -----\n")

root = tkinter.Tk()
print(root.tk)
print("is _default_root:", tkinter._default_root is root)

print("\n----- IntVar -----\n")

var = tkinter.IntVar()
print(var._tk)
```

Output:

```py
----- root -----

<_tkinter.tkapp object at 0x00000080E160E7B0>
is _default_root: True

----- IntVar -----

<_tkinter.tkapp object at 0x00000080E160E7B0>
```

The analogue of `root = tkinter.Tk()` in your script is `app = SampleApp()`. This is why these variables work in the classes associated with the SampleApp.

---

But the problem is not this error, but the fact that **the labels in the PageOne class are formed depending on the value entered in the Entry in the StartPage class**.

In your application, all frames are initialized in the SampleApp class's `__init__` method. This way you can access the frames through the controller (`self.controller.frames[page_name]`).

In this example, I am manipulating elements of one class from another. There are [other options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646605/how-to-access-variables-from-different-classes-in-tkinter) as well.

```py
import tkinter as tk                # python 3
from tkinter import font as tkfont
#from typing_extensions import IntVar  # python 3


class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    # same
    ...


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        
        # TypeError is thrown for self.some_input.get() if the value entered is not a number
        # see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140437/interactively-validating-entry-widget-content-in-tkinter
        # https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/entry-validation.html
        self.some_input = tk.IntVar()
        # set the default to 1
        self.some_input.set(1)
        self.some_entry = tk.Entry(self, width=8, textvariable=self.some_input)
        self.some_entry.pack()
        # button to open the next page with certain conditions
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text='Next Page', command=self.show_next_frame)
        button1.pack()

    def show_next_frame(self):
        if self.some_input.get() == 0:
            pass
        else:
            # create labels in the PageOne class using the entered value
            self.controller.frames["PageOne"].create_labels(self.some_input.get())
            # reset the default to 1
            self.some_input.set(1)
            # show the prepared page
            self.controller.show_frame("PageOne")


class PageOne(tk.Frame):   

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        
        self.labels_finanziatori = {
        'principale': [],
        'capitale_investito': [], 
        'tasso': [], 
        'tempo': []
        }
        dict_finanziatori = {
        'numero': [],
        'capitale_investito': [], 
        'tasso': [], 
        'tempo': [],
        }
        Finanziatore_Semplice = []

    def create_labels(self, some_input):
        k = 0

        for i in range(0, some_input): 
            # create new labels
            label = tk.Label(self, text="Dati finanziatore numero "+str(i+1) +":\n")
            label.grid(row=i*(k+1), column = 0)
            # you can save labels if needed
            self.labels_finanziatori['principale'].append(label)
            k = k+1
        # button on the side of the labels
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: self.controller.show_frame("StartPage")).grid(row=0, column=1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

> File "C:\Users\trevi\Anaconda\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line
> 317, in **init**
> self._root = master._root() AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_root'

You must start `root = tk.TK()` before `class StartPage(....`

In line  109, add `root.withdraw()` in `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Code:

```
root = tk.Tk()

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

:
:
:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root.withdraw()
:
:
```

Screenshot:

[image]