# Using Tkinter filedialog within a frame and accessing the output globally

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, scope

I am building my first GUI using tkinter and have come up against some problems. To make the code more modular, I am using an object-oriented approach, as seen in the code below. The basic idea is that I have defined classes for the DataFrame, MetaFrame and SaveFrame, which are all instantiated within the OptionsFrame, which then is instantiated within the MainWindow.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class DataFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, main, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(main, *args, **kwargs)
        # data frame elements
        self.data_label = ttk.Label(self, text="Add Data:")

        self.labelled_tweets_label = ttk.Label(self, text="Labelled-Tweets: ")
        self.labelled_tweets_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Browse")

        self.places_label = ttk.Label(self, text="Places: ")
        self.places_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Browse")

        self.plots_label = ttk.Label(self, text="Plots Path: ")
        self.plots_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Browse")

        self.submit_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Submit")

        # data frame layout
        self.data_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)
        self.labelled_tweets_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.labelled_tweets_button.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.places_label.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.places_button.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.plots_label.grid(row=3, column=0)
        self.plots_button.grid(row=3, column=1)
        self.submit_button.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)


class MetaFrame(ttk.Frame):
    ...


class SaveFrame(ttk.Frame):
    ...


class OptionsFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, main, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(main, *args, **kwargs)
        # options frame components
        self.data_frame = DataFrame(self)
        self.horiz1 = ttk.Separator(self, orient="horizontal")
        self.meta_frame = MetaFrame(self)
        self.horiz2 = ttk.Separator(self, orient="horizontal")
        self.save_frame = SaveFrame(self)

        # options frame layout
        self.data_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.horiz1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew", pady=30)
        self.meta_frame.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.horiz2.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="ew", pady=30)
        self.save_frame.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="s")

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.geometry("800x600")
        self.resizable(False, False)

        # configuration
        self.columnconfigure(index=0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(index=1, weight=2)

        # main frames
        self.options_frame = OptionsFrame(self, width=400, height=600, borderwidth=1)
        self.vert = ttk.Separator(self, orient="vertical")
        # main layout

        self.options_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.vert.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")

def main():
    root = MainWindow()
    root.mainloop()
```

The layout can be seen in the following image.

[image: GUI Layout]

This is the basic layout I want within the OptionsFrame. My confusion lies with creating filedialog methods for the three file browsing buttons within the DataFrame. I understand how to use the filedialog class to return the path to a given file, but then this value is restricted to be in the scope of the DataFrame.

I have a back-end that is already developed which requires these file paths, so ideally I would like to access them from the main() function. How is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: If the three filenames inside `DataFrame` are instance variables, for example `self.file1`, `self.file2` and `self.file3`, then you can use `root.options_frame.data_frame.file1` to access the first filename.  However it is better to create functions or properties to access those filenames in each class.

Comment: I've had decent luck sharing data between classes using the approach shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646605/how-to-access-variables-from-different-classes-in-tkinter). But @acw1668's answer is more straightforward if your app isn't especially large or complex!