# I can't access variables from one class in another one - Python

Tags: python, class, tkinter, tk-toolkit, ttk

I'm learning OOP and am making a calculator. I have classes for the main program (the parent program), buttons, and entries.

Main program:

```
class Program(tk.Tk): 

    def __init__(self, title, size): 
        super().__init__()
        self.title(title)
        self.geometry(f"{size[0]}x{size[1]}")

        # Program elements split into widget type
        self.entries = Entries(self) 
        self.output = Output(self)
        self.buttons = Buttons(self)
```

Entries:

```
class Entries(ttk.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, parent): 
        super().__init__(parent) 
        self.place(x = 0, y = 0) 

        # Calling widget generator and placer functions
        self.entryGen() 
        self.entryPlacer()
    
    def entryGen(self): # Create entry widgets
        self.firstTerm = ttk.Entry(self) 
        self.commonDifference = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.numberOfTerms = ttk.Entry(self)
    
    def entryPlacer(self): # Place entry widgets
        self.firstTerm.pack()
        self.commonDifference.pack()
        self.numberOfTerms.pack()
```

Buttons:

```
class Buttons(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.place(x = 0, y = 0)

        self.buttonGen()
        self.buttonPlacer()

    def buttonGen(self):
        self.clear = ttk.Button(self, text = "Clear", command = lambda: self.clear)
        self.calculate = ttk.Button(self, text = "Calculate", command = lambda: self.calculate)
    
    def buttonPlacer(self):
        self.clear.pack()
        self.calculate.pack()
    
    def clear(self):
        pass

    def calculate(self):
        entries = Entries()
        try:
            print(entries.firstTerm.get() + entries.commonDifference.get() + entries.numberOfTerms.get()) # Just some test code to see if it works, which it doesnt
        except:
            pass
```

I expect that when I create a reference to the Entries() class in my Buttons() class, I can access the variables I made in the Entries() class. This is not the case and I can't figure out why. I have looked at similar fixes and none seem to work.

Comment: You need to define the variables in `__init__`. They are not defined without calling the functions.

Comment: @Guy OP runs those other methods in init, it should be alright... but the code they showed uses Entries() while the init there takes a parent - so it should break even before that print

Comment: @tomasv 1. You do Entries() but the init in that class says you need to pass a parent - the code should therefore crash before the print line. If it doesn't crash, then it suggests you're running different code that you showed us. 2. Remove the try and bare except - you're hiding the error. Let the error crash your app and just show us what it says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues in your code:

- you should not create another instance of `Entries` inside `Buttons.calculate()`. Suggest to pass the instance to `Buttons` when it is created;
- the function `self.calculate()` is not called actually in the expression `command=lambda: self.calculate`. Use `command=self.calculate` instead. Same issue for `command=lambda: self.clear`;
- if the three inputs are numbers, you need to convert them to numbers before doing the calculation.

Updated code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Program(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, title, size):
        super().__init__()
        self.title(title)
        self.geometry(f"{size[0]}x{size[1]}")

        # Program elements split into widget type
        self.entries = Entries(self)
        self.output = Output(self)
        self.buttons = Buttons(self, self.entries) ### pass self.entries to class Buttons

class Entries(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.place(x = 0, y = 0)

        # Calling widget generator and placer functions
        self.entryGen()
        self.entryPlacer()

    def entryGen(self): # Create entry widgets
        self.firstTerm = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.commonDifference = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.numberOfTerms = ttk.Entry(self)

    def entryPlacer(self): # Place entry widgets
        self.firstTerm.pack()
        self.commonDifference.pack()
        self.numberOfTerms.pack()

class Buttons(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, entries): ### added argument entries
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.place(x = 200, y = 0)

        self.entries = entries  ### save the passed entries
        self.buttonGen()
        self.buttonPlacer()

    def buttonGen(self):
        self.clear = ttk.Button(self, text = "Clear", command = self.clear) ### remove lambda
        self.calculate = ttk.Button(self, text = "Calculate", command = self.calculate) ### remove lambda

    def buttonPlacer(self):
        self.clear.pack()
        self.calculate.pack()

    def clear(self):
        pass

    def calculate(self):
        try:
            ### convert inputs to numbers before calculation
            print(float(self.entries.firstTerm.get()) + float(self.entries.commonDifference.get()) + float(self.entries.numberOfTerms.get()))
        except Exception as ex:
            ### better show the execption
            print(ex)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works great! I'm confused how it doesn't automatically fill the variables when you type self.entries.firstTerm, almost as it doesn't exist, but regardless it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Buttons` class won't have direct access to your `Entries` class unless you pass the `entries` instance (or at least *an* `entries` instance) to it at `__init__`

What it *does* have access to, however, is the `Program` class via `parent`

The approach I've taken in the past is as follows:

```
class Buttons(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.entries = parent.entries
```

This way, your child class `Buttons` can access `Entries`' instance attributes through their shared parent class via the instance `entries` created at `Program.__init__()`.

You could update the `Entries` class `__init__` in a similar way so that it too can access attributes from `parent`

I also tend to take the approach outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33650527/8512262) by creating a dictionary of "shared" variables within my root application class